# Languages with words for "childless wife" or "childless husband"?

Tags: list-of-languages, sociolinguistics

Are there any languages words for a "childless wife" and "childless husband"?

Comment: You mean the specific situation where someone who has a child (from a previous relationship or marriage) marries someone who does not have any children? Fairly normal situation, probably throughout history, but I don’t recall ever hearing of a word for that specific notion, no. Also, I presume you got your genders switched around there – it’s highly unlikely that any language would have a masculine word for ‘childless wife’ and a feminine word for ‘childless husband’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Childless" in English can apply to a male or female, but I'm looking for languages in which one word for "childless" applies to a husband and another to a wife.

Comment: Yes, I understood that – I was just saying it would be very unusual to use the masculine word for the wife and the feminine word for the husband. In any language where masculine and feminine are existing categories, you’d expect it to be the other way around (masculine = husband; feminine = wife).

Comment: In Slavic languages, "childless" is an adjective, and Slavic adjectives agree in gender with the noun they refer to, so there are actually 2 words "childless", one word for "childless" which  is masculine and applies to a husband (Ukrainian _бездітний_,  Russian _бездетный_)  and another feminine, to a wife Ukr. _бездітна_,  Ru. _бездетная_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I understand that.

Comment: @YellowSky That's true in many languages with masculine and feminine words, but the examples you give are really different inflections of the same word.